# Parse Complex Nested Data From server

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to parse data i've received from the server so as to display it into a UIPicker view. but it's too complex for me to parse and get it displayed into UIPIcker View. Whats the best way i can parse the following data into and make it ready for a `UIPickerView`.
This is the session trying to parse the information from the server

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://dummy.com/api")!

    let request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if error == nil {

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                guard let parseJSON = json else{

                    print("Error While Parsing")
                    return
                }
                print(parseJSON)

                let responseDic = parseJSON["response"] as? NSDictionary
                let utilityCode = responseDic?["utility_code"] as? String

                if utilityCode == "AFRICELL" {

                    let africellPackages = responseDic?["packages"] as! NSArray

                    print(africellPackages)
                }


            }catch{
                return
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

The following data is the response from the server when the GET request is made.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "response": [
    {
      "utility_code": "AIRTEL",
      "packages": [
        {
          "package_id": 33,
          "package_name": "Daily 10MB",
          "package_code": "6000",
          "package_price": 300
        },
        {
          "package_id": 34,
          "package_name": "Daily 20MB",
          "package_code": "6002",
          "package_price": 500
        },
        {
          "package_id": 65,
          "package_name": "Weekly Roaming 200MB",
          "package_code": "6030",
          "package_price": 100000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "utility_code": "AFRICELL",
      "packages": [
        {
          "package_id": 68,
          "package_name": "Daily 10 MB",
          "package_code": "5000",
          "package_price": 290
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "utility_code": "SMART",
      "packages": [
        {
          "package_id": 69,
          "package_name": "Daily 50 MB",
          "package_code": "8000",
          "package_price": 500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "utility_code": "SMILE",
      "packages": [
        {
          "package_id": 70,
          "package_name": "Smile 1GB",
          "package_code": "7006",
          "package_price": 32000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Cheers and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All examples below are provided without error checking for brevity. For production code, you should handle errors properly.

---

## Swift 3 without any external framework

Most of the work to decode JSON manually involves defining the data model:

```
struct JSONResponse {
    var status: String
    var response: [Utility]

    init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.status = jsonDict["status"] as! String
        self.response = [Utility]()

        let response = jsonDict["response"] as! [AnyObject]
        for r in response.map({ $0 as! [String: AnyObject] }) {
            let utility = Utility(jsonDict: r)
            self.response.append(utility)
        }
    }
}

struct Utility {
    var code: String
    var packages: [Package]

    init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.code = jsonDict["utility_code"] as! String
        self.packages = [Package]()

        let packages = jsonDict["packages"] as! [AnyObject]
        for p in packages.map({ $0 as! [String: AnyObject] }) {
            let package = Package(jsonDict: p)
            self.packages.append(package)
        }
    }
}

struct Package {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var code: String
    var price: Int

    init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = jsonDict["package_id"] as! Int
        self.name = jsonDict["package_name"] as! String
        self.code = jsonDict["package_code"] as! String
        self.price = jsonDict["package_price"] as! Int
    }
}
```

And how to use it:

```
let jsonDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: AnyObject]
let jsonResponse = JSONResponse(jsonDict: jsonDict)
let utilities = jsonResponse.response

print(utilities)
```

---

## Swift 3 with ObjectMapper

Decoding JSON is it of a pain in standard Swift. You need an external JSON framework like `ObjectMapper` to ease the pain in mapping between the JSON data and your data model. Install `ObjectMapper` from CocoaPod or Carthage.

First, define your data model in a separate file:

```
import ObjectMapper

struct JSONResponse : Mappable {
    var status: String?
    var response: [Utility]?

    init?(map: Map) { }
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.status     <- map["status"]
        self.response   <- map["response"]
    }
}

struct Utility : Mappable {
    var code: String?
    var packages: [Package]?

    init?(map: Map) { }
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.code           <- map["code"]
        self.packages       <- map["packages"]
    }
}

struct Package : Mappable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var code: String?
    var price: Int?

    init?(map: Map) { }
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id             <- map["package_id"]
        self.name           <- map["package_name"]
        self.code           <- map["package_code"]
        self.price          <- map["package_price"]
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to map JSON to your object like this:

```
// data is what your get in the dataTask's completion block
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
if let jsonResponse = JSONResponse(JSONString: jsonString),
    let utilities = jsonResponse.response {
    print(utilities)
}
```

Everything has to be declared optional because you don't know if the value will be in the JSON string or not.

---

## In Swift 4

Things get a lot simpler in Swift 4 with the new `Encodable` and `Decodable` protocols. Both combined to form the `Encodable` protocol (yes, [protocol composition](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID282) is a new thing in Swift 4). You no longer need `ObjectMapper` in Swift 4.

You still need to define your data model first:

```
struct JSONResponse : Codable {
    var status: String
    var response: [Utility]
}

struct Utility : Codable {
    var code: String
    var packages: [Package]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "utility_code"
        case packages
    }
}

struct Package : Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var code: String
    var price: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "package_id"
        case name = "package_name"
        case code = "package_code"
        case price = "package_price"
    }
}
```

And here's how you use the new `JSONDecoder` struct in Swift 4:

```
let jsonRepsonse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse.self, from: data)
let utilities = jsonRepsonse.response
print(utilities)
```

---

## So what's going on here?

Both `ObjectMapper` and `Codable` map the values in JSON to your data model.

In `ObjectMapper`, you have to explicitly list which property maps to which value in JSON in a function named `mapping(map:)`:

```
mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.id             <- map["package_id"]
    self.name           <- map["package_name"]
    self.code           <- map["package_code"]
    self.price          <- map["package_price"]
}
```

`<-` is the "mapping operator" defined by `ObjectMapper` (it's not in the Standard Library).

With Swift 4's `Codable`, the compiler automates a lot of things for you, which makes it appear magical and confusing at first. Essentially you define your mappings in an enum called `CodingKeys`:

```
struct JSONResponse : Codable {
    var status: String
    var response: [Utility]

    // Define your JSON mappings here       
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status"
        case response = "response"
    }
}

struct Package : Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var code: String
    var price: Int

    // Define your JSON mappings here
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "package_id"
        case name = "package_name"
        case code = "package_code"
        case price = "package_price"
    }
}
```

If your JSON keys are the same as your property name, like in the `JSONResponse` struct, you don't have to define the explicit value for each `case` and you can simply write:

```
struct JSONResponse : Codable {
    var status: String
    var response: [Utility]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status         // no explicit value here
        case response
    }
}
```

Better yet, since every JSON key is the same as your property name, you can omit the `CodingKeys` enum all together and let the compiler handle that for you:

```
// All you need to do is to conform it to Codable
// CodingKeys is generated automatically
struct JSONResponse : Codable {
    var status: String
    var response: [Utility]
}
```

To learn more about `Codable`, watch the [What's new in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/) session from WWDC 2017.

Comment: Hey man, This is a brilliant Answer! And i don't want to take away any credit from it, but i'm relatively new to swift and would like to stay away from frameworks for now. Also i'm 70% done with the project so i can't upgrade to swift 4(at least i don't know to and it would set me back coz i'd have to learn). 
This is a brilliant answer and we should leave it for the community, but what if i wanted to use swift 3 and no framework?
Thank you very  much and i appreciate the time invested into that answer!

Comment: Decoding JSON manually is a pain in the neck. See my edited answer